# Data grid text column single-click edit mode

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in XAML where every column is a text column.  I define a column template for every column.  I want to be able to click once on a cell and be in edit mode rather than having to double click on it.  I have followed this: http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing and I have not had any success.  Right now, the sample code shown below will only bring the cell into focus in a single click, it will not actually put me in edit mode.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the data grid:

```
    <DataGrid
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        x:Name="grdData"
        FontFamily="Verdana"
        Height="200"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        RowHeight="22"
        CanUserAddRows="True"
        CanUserDeleteRows="True"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeRows="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}"
        SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
        SelectionMode="Extended">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <EventSetter 
                    Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                    Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Here is a sample column template that I define:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="60">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Style="{StaticResource tbkStyleGridHeader}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Text="GelPak Location"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Style="{StaticResource tbkStyleGridCell}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Text="{Binding GelPakLocation}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox
                            Text="{Binding GelPakLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
    private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell) sender;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            if (!cell.IsFocused)
            {
                cell.Focus();
            }
            DataGrid dataGrid = FindVisualParent<DataGrid>(cell);
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                if (dataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                {
                    if (!cell.IsSelected)
                    {
                        cell.IsSelected = true;
                        cell.IsEditing = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridRow row = FindVisualParent<DataGridRow>(cell);
                    if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
                    {
                        row.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement parent = element;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = parent as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it:

Following this tutorial:  http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing

I just changed my DataGridTemplateColumns to DataGridTextBoxColumns.  In doing this, I had to get rid of the CellTemplate and CellEditingTemplate elements.

Now my column template looks like this:

```
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Width="60"
                Binding="{Binding GelPakLocation}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Style="{StaticResource tbkStyleGridHeader}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Text="GelPak Location"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Doing this also allowed me to delete this line in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler:

```
cell.IsEditing = true;
```

It seems like this line didn't really do anything anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a TextBox in the actual CellTemplate and remove the CellEditingTemplate alltogether.  Then you can use a focus trigger on the textboxes to (for example) change the background color and readonly property of the text box as it gains focus...